# Why use And over AndAlso?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm fairly new to .NET programming, and I recently stumbled across AndAlso. As I understand it, AndAlso evaluates the first expression, if it is true then it evaluates the second...and so on. And, on the other hand, always evaluates all terms in the expression.

If my understanding is correct, would AndAlso always be (marginally) more efficient. If this is the case, why use And at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between And and AndAlso in VB.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302047/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-andalso-in-vb-net)

Comment: I believe I understand the difference between the two. My question is more towards why And is ever preferable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(OrElse and Or) and (AndAlso and And) - When to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8409467/11683)

Comment: Same problem...that link discusses code correctness, which I believe I understand.

Comment: It's pretty clear based on the links. AND is a bitwise operator and evaluate both sides, if you don't need to do that than use AndAlso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`And` is bitwise. `AndAlso` is boolean.

*Correctness wise*, if we disregard short-circuting, `And` can always be used in all cases where `AndAlso` can be used ([unless you get creative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24684955/11683)), but the other way round is not true.

That is, `And` is a "universal" operator that will "do the right thing" in both the bitwise and logical contexts, but is not optimized for either. `AndAlso` can only be used in the boolean context, but it is optimized for it.

Visual Basic did not use to have `AndAlso`, so `And` was the only choice. Now that VB has `AndAlso`, `And` <s>should</s> may be used for:

- bitwise math (performing the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) over two numbers)
- expressions with side effects (you want to disable short-circuiting and have both parts of the expression always evaluated). I would certainly not call this a recommended practice, because you might end up with very unobvious code, but it is probably okay if you have legacy code upgraded from VB6.

Comment: Having an expression with side-effects in the second part of an if statement would be a big code smell. So `And` should really only be used for bitwise math.

Comment: @Meta-Knight I wasn't trying to say one should actually do it, rather, that it can be done and it distinguishes `And` from `AndAlso`. Oh wait, I actually did say "should..."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a little of a personal choice. but I tend to think `And` should *never* used.
Of course `And` is needed for bitwise operation but it's not really the question here (you don't have choice for bitwise conjunction between `And` and `AndAlso`).
I don't like the "side-effect" trick ; if you want side effects perform them and **then** test the result values

```
Dim result1 = SideEffect1(), result2 = SideEffect2()
If result1 AndAlso result2 Then ' ...
```

is IMHO better than

```
If SideEffect1() And SideEffect2() Then ' ...
```

The intent is clearer but sure both way are possible.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful if you have an expression with side effects. For example, your second expression is a function that you always want to run, regardless of what evaluates before it.