# VB6 multiple IF statement bizarre issue

Tags: debugging, if-statement, vb6, multiple-conditions

Got a bizarre issue in an `IF` statement with multiple conditions.
The last working version looks like:

```
If VAR1 = "SCRT" And InStr("|TEC|FIN|", "|" & VAR2 & "|")) And VAR3 = 1 Then
```

And now, I implement another condition to statement:

```
If VAR1 = "SCRT" And InStr("|TEC|FIN|", "|" & VAR2 & "|")) And (VAR3 = 1 or VAR3 = 15) Then
```

With this values:
VAR1: "" (empty)
VAR2: "FIN"
VAR3: 1

The code it will work fine in debug. The bizarre is compiling and running on the production environment, the condition passed even with the first condition not ok.

Already logged the values to check.
The production environment has the same files (libraries).

The only thing that changed besides the condition is the Option Explicit in the begin of this module.

Thanks!!

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` and `VAR1` is null?

Comment: Instr returns the position of the match (either 1 or 5 or 0). The And operator is bitwise in VB6. A TRUE value is -1, so all bits are set. You should check for result of Instr being > 0. That will return either 0 or -1 and your expression will be more correct.

Comment: I saw this, but in this case vb6 implicitly convert any value >0 to True.

Comment: Only by luck. If you had two Instr conditions for example, it may fail. This would fail: If InStr("abc", "a") And InStr("abc", "b") Then

Comment: Ok.... this is an change that it'll be changed! =)
But it's not the resolution.

Comment: You have mismatched parentheses. Otherwise it may or may not be a Possible duplicate of [Odd behavior with boolean if statement in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24684955/11683).

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but that's just way too hard to parse, and for no good reason. When dealing with `And` conditions, you're far better off using nested `If`s, placing the least likely conditions first and the most expensive tests last where possible. This is much clearer, and almost certainly faster:

```
If VAR1 = "SCRT" Then
 If InStr("|TEC|FIN|", "|" & VAR2 & "|")) > 0 Then
  If (VAR3 = 1) or (VAR3 = 15) Then
```

This allows short-circuiting, which is otherwise unavailable in VB6. Code doesn't run faster just because it's on one line.

Two changes: test `If Instr > 0` rather than just `If Instr`. Yes, VB will evaluate a successful test to `True / False`, ***but*** it will never evaluate the `Not` of that expression to `False`, which will someday bite you. Believe it. (-:

Second change: I used parens to force the order of precedence for the `Or` conditions. There are rules, but you could get something like `If VAR3 = (1 Or VAR3) = 15` when you least expect it. Be explicit and there are no surprises.

Comment: Checking > 0 is also better 'defensive' programming. Since it is more explicit some future programmer is less likely to make a change which breaks it.

Comment: I was simplifying, but this is only one of many conditions in a list of rules. The real function has a lot of elseif's and if I put one condition inside another, the code will messy...

First change: I've already put the >0 ... =D
Second change: didn't understand the condition `If VAR3 = (1 Or VAR3) = 15`. Why you put the parens like that?

Thanks!!

Comment: @FernandoMoreno - That was just an example of the kind of problem you might encounter if your understanding of the rules of precedence aren't the same as the compiler's. Look in the code block for my actual recommendation. Be explicit: add parens to force evaluation when there might be confusion -- it never hurts,

Comment: Also, a tangle of `if`s and `elseif`s is usually a sign that you should be trying a different approach

Comment: I´m still confused about If InStr("|TEC|FIN|", "|" & VAR2 & "|")): my confusion comes from ONE opening "(" and TWO closing ")"

Comment: @nabuchodonossor - Good catch. I just pasted that from the OP's code but it's clearly an error and would never run, so it can't be what he actually tested. A good reason not to post air code when asking for help (-: